# jquery button affecting all instances in loop

Tags: jquery, loops, button

I've got a form that uses jquery/Ajax to update my database without a refresh.
The jquery fades out the radio options on submit, and then shows another button in case the user would like to change their selection.

My problem is that once the user submits their decisions, if they click the "change your mind" button, the jquery brings back the radios for ALL instances below.

How can that "change your mind" button bring back the radios for ONLY that instance?
Sorry for the complicated scenario and chunk of code. If you need more info or explanation, just ask!

Thanks.

```
<? $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE Job='$job'") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){ ?>
        <div class='tile'>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $('document').ready(function(){
                    $('#form<?= $row['Id'] ?>').ajaxForm({
                        target: '#preview<?= $row['Id'] ?>',
                        success: function() {
                            $('#formbox<?= $row['Id'] ?>').fadeOut('slow'),
                            $('#preview<?= $row['Id'] ?>').fadeIn('slow');
                            $("button").click(function () {
                                $("#preview<?= $row['Id'] ?>").fadeOut("slow"),
                                $("#formbox<?= $row['Id'] ?>").fadeIn("slow");});
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script> 

            <div class='details'>
                <div id='radios' style='position:relative; height:25px;'>
                    <div id="preview<?= $row['Id'] ?>" style="width:258px; margin-left:-129px; left:50%; display:none; position:absolute;">
                        <button>Way to go! Click here to change your mind.</button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="formbox<?= $row['Id'] ?>" style='position:absolute;'> 
                    <form name='' id='form<?= $row['Id'] ?>' action='js/submit.php' method='post'>
                        <label>Keep:</label><input type='radio' name='dec[]' value='keep' <? if($row['Dec1']=='keep'){echo "checked='checked'";} ?> >
                        <label>Donate:</label><input type='radio' name='dec[]' value='donate' <? if($row['Dec1']=='donate'){echo "checked='checked'";} ?> >
                        <label>Sell:</label><input type='radio' name='dec[]' value='sell' <? if($row['Dec1']=='sell'){echo "checked='checked'";} ?> >
                        <label>Trash:</label><input type='radio' name='dec[]' value='trash' <? if($row['Dec1']=='trash'){echo "checked='checked'";} ?> >
                        <label>Give To:</label><input type='text' name='dec[]' size='15' <? if($row['Dec1']!='keep' && $row['Dec1']!='donate' && $row['Dec1']!='sell' && $row['Dec1']!='trash'){echo "value='".$row['Dec1']."'";} ?> >
                        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?= $row['Id'] ?>' />
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<? 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that every time you submit the form, you add click handler to the all the buttons that fades in that set of radios. When you submit a different form, you never remove the previous handlers, so it fades them all in again.

Instead of having lots of different handlers, with `$row['Id']` substituted into each, you should bind a the `.ajaxForm()` to a class. It should make use of `$(this)` and DOM traversal functions to operate on just the form you clicked on.

Also, I don't think it's related to the problem, but your `id='radios'` doesn't have the row ID appended, so you're creating duplicate IDs for those elements.

I think this should do it: ([FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/SLhsh/3/))

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('.form').ajaxForm({
        success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, elem) {
            var formbox = elem.closest('.formbox');
            formbox.fadeOut('slow');
            formbox.siblings(".preview").fadeIn('slow');
        }
    });
    $("button").click(function() {
        var preview = $(this).closest(".preview");
        preview.fadeOut("slow");
        preview.siblings(".formbox").fadeIn("slow");
    });
});​
</script> 

<? $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE Job='$job'") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){ ?>
        <div class='tile'>
            <div class='details'>
                <div class='radios' style='position:relative; height:25px;'>
                    <div class="preview" style="width:258px; margin-left:-129px; left:50%; display:none; position:absolute;">
                        <button>Way to go! Click here to change your mind.</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="formbox" style='position:absolute;'> 
                    <form name='' class='form' action='js/submit.php' method='post'>
                        <label>Keep:</label><input type='radio' name='dec[]' value='keep' <? if($row['Dec1']=='keep'){echo "checked='checked'";} ?> >
                        <label>Donate:</label><input type='radio' name='dec[]' value='donate' <? if($row['Dec1']=='donate'){echo "checked='checked'";} ?> >
                        <label>Sell:</label><input type='radio' name='dec[]' value='sell' <? if($row['Dec1']=='sell'){echo "checked='checked'";} ?> >
                        <label>Trash:</label><input type='radio' name='dec[]' value='trash' <? if($row['Dec1']=='trash'){echo "checked='checked'";} ?> >
                        <label>Give To:</label><input type='text' name='dec[]' size='15' <? if($row['Dec1']!='keep' && $row['Dec1']!='donate' && $row['Dec1']!='sell' && $row['Dec1']!='trash'){echo "value='".$row['Dec1']."'";} ?> >
                        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?= $row['Id'] ?>' />
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<? 
}
```

Comment: hmm...I've applied your code, but the .formbox is not fading out on submit. The query is running correctly, but I'm not getting the ".formbox" to fade out and ".preview" to fade in. Any ideas?

Comment: FYI: I'm using the following plugin to submit the form: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ :Just in case you think it might be affecting the jquery. I don't believe it is, but you may see it differently.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out from `.ajaxForm`. The documentation says that the 4th argument to the callback should be the form element, so I thought `$('.CLASSNAME', elem)` should find those elements and fade them. Maybe it should be `$('.CLASSNAME', $(elem))`?

Comment: I changed the syntax on the 'elem' for both .formbox and .preview - still no luck.

Comment: Is it putting the responseText in the DIV? Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the callback function in Firebug/Dev Toosls?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but the response text (the 'change my mind' button) is already in the div, it is just set to display:none at the start. I'm afraid I don't know enough jquery to set a breakpoint. That's sort of why I'm here! haha

Comment: You don't need to "know jQuery" to set a breakpoint. Just open the developer tools or Firebug, find the line in your script, click on the line number, and a breakpoint is set (that's how it works in Chrome Dev Tools, I'm assuming it's similar in Firebug). This site isn't here for others to do your work for you -- you need to learn how to walk on your own. Meanwhile, I'll see if I can set up something in jsfiddle to figure it out.

Comment: Of course. It's never been my intent to have others "do the work for me". I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: I've got the fadeout working -- I was navigating the DOM in the wrong direction. However, the button doesn't appear when it fades in. In your original code, you have `target: '#preview<?= $row['Id'] ?>'`, which replaces the `preview` DIV with the response text, and I reproduced this in my code. But this was where you had the "change your mind" button, so it's being overwritten. You need to find a new place to put the responseText to avoid this problem.

Comment: You're right about the responseText, I had gotten that location mixed up. It is now located in the 'submit.php' file that actually runs the query. Your JSfiddle looks great, but after implementing that code the browser now continues onto the submit.php page. I'm sorry, I've been poking around the dev tools for a while now and am just completely lost. You've been extremely helpful and I'd certainly appreciate your help, but I fully understand that you can't just do this for me. I'd ask that you only continue helping me if you truly have the free time. I don't want to test your patience! Thanks!

Comment: This is AJAX, submit.php isn't supposed to print a page, it's supposed to return data to be used by the Javascript (e.g. a success/failure indicator). I've changed my fiddle so it ignores the response, so you can see it working correctly. I also fixed a bug in the fadeIn, it was looking for class button instead of element type.

Comment: You sir, are a good man! I sorted out the Ajax issue and found a way for the response text to come in properly. Thanks again for your patience!